# Trouble handling exceptions with a SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, sqldatasource, registerstartupscript

I having trouble handling exception of a SqlDataSource. The SqlDataSource is currently being used by my ListView. My code doesn't seem to display an error message even though it looks correct to me. I can't seem to pinpoint the mistake.

**Code:**

```
 protected void CustomerSQLDataSource_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        //Show error message
        string myStringVariable = "Error";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);

        //Set the exception handled property 
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Comment: Out of interest whats the exception message? eg `e.Exception.ToString()` or `e.Exception.Message`

Comment: Lol in not talking about the type or the method\property you use. I'm interested to know what exception is!

Comment: Lol sorry my mistake. 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_IBanking_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "C:\TEMP\EAPJ\APP_DATA\EAPJDATABASE.MDF", table "dbo.IBanking", column 'NRIC'.
The statement has been terminated.